# Ctrl + F, see matches in bar visual studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio-2022

When using the ctrl + F search function VS2022 in a tab I used to be able to see all matches of my search on the scrollbar in the form of little dots (like break point dots sort of).

Easily enabling me see if there are many matches to my search in the particular document.

Now however these "dots" on the scrollbar when searching is gone thus I have to do "Find next" to go through the document/tab to see where the matches are instead of easily getting a good overview.

PS - I do not want to use ctrl + shift + f for this.

How do I get back a "search result" in the scroll bar that show matches of my ctrl + F search?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for the "Show annotations over vertical scroll bar" group of options under Tools > Options > Text Editor > All Languages > Scoll Bars.

[image: Screenshot showing the "Show annotations over vertical scroll bar" options]